# How can I put multiple value inputs in an UITextField to get their outputs?

Tags: ios, swift, binary, decimal

I'm building an iOS app that deals with binary and decimal outputs when a user types in a binary or decimal number. I have it to where a user can calculate one value, but how can I get it to where they can calculate multiple values in the same UITextField? Like they can type in 145, 10010110, 10011101, etc. and it can return the opposite binary or decimal.

My existing code is:

```
class BinaryDecimal {
    var bits: [Int]?
    var integer: Int?

    init(_ bits: [Int]) {
        self.bits = bits
    }

    init(_ decimal: Int) {
        self.integer = decimal
    }

    func calculateBinaryValueForInt() -> String {
        var newInt = integer!
        let rows = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
        var binaryRows: [Int] = []
        for row in rows {
            let binaryDigit = oneOrZero(forValue: newInt, withBitValue: row)
            binaryRows.append(binaryDigit)
            if binaryDigit == 1 {
                newInt = newInt - row
            }
        }
        let stringFromIntArray = binaryRows.map { String($0) }
        return stringFromIntArray.joined()
    }

    func calculateIntValueForBinary() -> String {
        var value = 0
        var multiplier = 1
        guard let bits = bits else { return "Error" }
        for bit in bits.reversed() {
            let newValue = bit * multiplier
            value = value + newValue
            multiplier = multiplier * 2
        }
        return String(value)
    }

    func oneOrZero(forValue value: Int, withBitValue bitvalue: Int) -> Int {
        if value - bitvalue >= 0 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If a user types `100`, how do you know if that is decimal or binary?

Comment: I put two buttons named "Binary" and "Decimal". When they type in 100, they can choose either button. It'll show the value in the UITextField.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. You can use `String(integer, radix: 2)` and just add leading zeros to pad it to 8 digits if desired

Comment: To calculateIntValueForBinary() -> String?

Comment: to calculate binary for Int `var binary: String? {
        guard let integer = integer else { return nil }
        let binary = String(integer, radix: 2)
        return repeatElement("0", count: 8-binary.count) + binary
    }`

Comment: I'm getting a 'Nil is incompatible with return type 'String'' error for guard let integer = integer else { return nil }

Comment: Do you want my repo Leo?